# Some Javascript elements not working in Chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-8.1

I am finding that I am viewing some websites lately and some are not loading as they should, like the JS elements are being ignored.

An example would be http://www.powerhouse-company.com/ , it loads with the video background and javascript hover effects in IE fine. But in FF and Chrome it doesn't, it shows this instead: http://prntscr.com/3l00i3

Normally I would think it was a website issue, however on my work PC the website displays as it should on all browsers. The only difference to my work PC is that I am using Windows 8 , but I do not see how that makes any difference. I have cleared all settings and cache etc and performed every recommend 'fix' I have found on the net but nothing.

Any Idea's?

Many Thanks,
James

Comment: Working fine on Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 m

Comment: Works fine for me too on Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 m. Try disabling any extensions you have installed. Sounds like one of them is misbehaving. Also working on Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: Thanks, already disabled them all but no luck and same chrome version.

Comment: As for the example you shared, I would guess the issue is related to your flash plugin or some plugin blocking iframes ( since that's the content missing according to your screenshot. Try (re)installing the plugin and check?

Comment: Hi Ramy, there is no flash or iframes on said site. It is the JS that is not 'activating' etc. There is no plugins/extensions on my FF or Chrome and it's so weird that it works ok on IE.

Comment: Anyone else got a idea?